# How does join() work in java? Does it guarantee the execution before main()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand the code flow with join().

```
public class Multi extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Multi();
        Thread t2 = new Multi();
        Thread t3 = new Multi();
        Thread t4 = new Multi();

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        t2.start();        
        t3.start();
        try {
            t3.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }        
        t4.start();

        System.out.println("........" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        t1.setName("A");
        t2.setName("B");
        t3.setName("C");
        t4.setName("D");
    }
}
```

The output is always, as i observe after running program many times, that `thread t1` executes first and it will `complete it's execution` without any context switching, and whenever `t3 will start it will completes it's execution`. Is my understanding clear?

I observe something that, if no join is used, `main()` executes anywhere b/w the execution of threads, means i see `........main` output in between the outputs of my program, but after `join()` it executes always after thread t3. Here is my doubt as `main()` starts before the `join()` syntax, so it should not follow the t3/t1 thread completion? Does it make sense or something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a proper understanding what a thread is? Are you aware of the term "parallel execution" ?

Comment: join() does what its javadoc says it does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Comment: @JBNizet I believe the OP just didn't understand it. This piece of javadoc is actually not very clear, IMO.

Comment: @Joffrey: you must be new here ;-)

Comment: @JBNizet Haha, well I know people often ask questions like *"what does this method do"* without reading the doc, but this time I have to admit that the doc is unclear. I remember me having doubts the first time I read the docs about multithreading, interruptions and all that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Short answer

> How does `join()` work in java?

I grant you that [the javadoc for `join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) is a little bit unclear, because it's not obvious who `this` refers to when you first read it.

It means that the thread calling `t.join()` blocks until the thread `t` has finished its execution. If `t` has already finished when the current thread calls `t.join()`, then the current thread does not stop and just keeps going. 
The word `this` in the doc refers to `t` here, not to the thread that calls the method.

> Does it guarantee the execution before `main()`?
>
> [...] if no join is used, `main()` executes anywhere b/w the execution of threads [...]

You shouldn't consider `main()` as a whole. Parts of `main()` are executed before the other threads, parts of it in parallel, and parts of it after. That's actually what `start()` and `join()` control. Let me explain below.

### What happens in your `main()`

Here is the sequence of events regarding `t1.start()` and `t1.join()`. You can obviously think the same way for `t3`.

1. The instructions of `main()` preceding `t1.start()` are executed
2. `t1.start()` starts the thread `t1` (`t1.run()` might not start right away.)
3. The instructions of `main()` between `t1.start()` and `t1.join()` are executed in parallel(*) of the ones in `t1.run()`.
   *Note: You have none in your example, so only t1.run() instructions are executed at this moment.*
4. `t1.join()`:

   - if `t1.run()` has already finished, nothing happens and `main()` keeps going
   - if `t1.run()` has not finished yet, **the main thread stops and waits** until `t1.run()` finishes. Then `t1.run()` finishes, and then `main()` resumes.
5. The instructions of `main()` after `t1.join()` are executed

Here you can see that:

- the part of `main()` preceding `t1.start()` is guaranteed to be executed *before* `t1.run()`
- the part of `main()` following `t1.join()` is guaranteed to be executed *after* `t1.run()`

(*) see below section about parallelism

### What I mean by *"executed in parallel"*

Suppose you have these 2 sets of instructions being executed in 2 threads A and B:

```
// Thread A                   |     // Thread B
                              | 
System.out.println("A1");     |     System.out.println("B1");
System.out.println("A2");     |     System.out.println("B2");
System.out.println("A3");     |     System.out.println("B3");
```

If these 2 threads are "executed in parallel", this means 3 things:

- the order of execution of the instructions of thread A is guaranteed:
  A1 will execute before A2, and A2 before A3.
- the order of execution of the instructions of thread B is guaranteed:
  B1 will execute before B2, and B2 before B3.
- however, A's and B's instructions can be interlaced, which means all of the following are possible (and more):

> A1, B1, A2, B2, B3, A3
>
> B1, B2, A1, B3, A2, A3
>
> A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3  // special case where A's are all executed before B's
>
> B1, B2, B3, A1, A2, A3  // special case where B's are all executed before A's

---

***Note:*** this section dealt with parallelism as an illusion created by the OS to make the user feel like things run at the same time, where actually there is only one core executing instructions sequentially, jumping from one process/thread to another.

*In fact, an A instruction and a B instruction could be executed simultaneously (real parallelism) on 2 separate cores. The 3 bullet points above still stand anyway. As @jameslarge pointed out, usually we model concurrency with a sequence of events, even for multicores. This leaves aside the concept of simultaneity of 2 events, which does not bring anything useful but complications.*

Comment: The instructions between `t1.start()` and `t1.join()` in the `main()` method **might** get executed in parallel of `t1`’s `run()` method. There’s no guaranty that they will.

Comment: @Holger When I say *executed in parallel*, I mean there is no guarantee about the order of execution (interlacing) of the instructions of one thread and the other. This includes the cases where all instructions of one thread happen before those of the other.

Comment: For the advanced programmer that inclusion is understandable. But I think for the knowledge level of the questioner it would be useful to mention these possibilities explicitly.

Comment: @Holger You're right. I'll update my post to explain.

Comment: @Joffrey said, "an A instruction and a B instruction could be executed simultaneously". That is true, but in most mathematical models of concurrent computing, events are never simultaneous.  Either it can be shown that A happens before B, or it can be shown that B happens before A, or neither case can be shown.  Eliminating the concept of "simultaneous" simplifies the algebra.  _Events_ are never simultaneous, but _intervals_ (e.g., a function call that has a "begin" event and an "end" event) can _overlap_.

Comment: @jameslarge That's true, it's virtually impossible for 2 CPU instructions to be executed at the very same moment, even on 2 separate cores.

Answer (score 1):

Joins

The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

t.join();
causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as long as you specify.

Like sleep, join responds to an interrupt by exiting with an InterruptedException.