# Java - Make threads concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading

How do i make threads execute concurrently? I have the code below. Process T.Create(mt); completes its entire task before c.Consume(mt) even begins. I put a sleep function in the T.Create(mt); function, but the c.Consume(mt) still will not start until after it has completely finished. I am trying to add objects to a heap with the create process and remove them from the heap with the consume process, such that they undo each others work.

```
package javaapplication2;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class JavaApplication2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewThread T = new NewThread();
    T.start();
    NewThread c = new NewThread();
    c.start();
    MinHeap mt = new MinHeap(50);
    T.Create(mt);
    c.Consume(mt);

}

class NewThread extends Thread
{
    NewThread()
    {

    }
    public void run(MinHeap minHeap)
    {

    }
    public void Create(MinHeap minHeap)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(40) + 1; 

        System.out.println("num = "  + randNum);


        int i =0;
       Node n = new Node();
       n.setID(randNum);
       minHeap.first(n);
        while (minHeap.getSize() < 15)
        {
        n = new Node();
        randNum = rand.nextInt(40) + 1; 
        n.setID(randNum);
        minHeap.insert(n);
        System.out.print("Input: " + randNum + " Heap = ");
        minHeap.print();
        try{Thread.sleep(800);}catch(Exception e){}
        }

        minHeap.print();
        minHeap.remove();
        System.out.println("========= size = " + minHeap.getSize());
        minHeap.print();
    }

    public void Consume(MinHeap minHeap)
    {
        while (minHeap.getSize() > 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Consume - Heap = ");
            minHeap.remove();
            minHeap.print();
            try{Thread.sleep(800);}catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's `NewThread`? What do `Create()` and `Consume()` do? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Create puts objects on a heap, and consume removes objects from a heap. I want them to work concurrently together, such that one basically undoes the work of the other. I am trying to figure out what to do that makes these two functions run simultaneously. Right now, one process runs completely and then the other runs.

Comment: I'm not looking for a description. I'm looking for a [mcve].

Comment: Try using `Join`. Read  [Java Doc: Join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html) or [SO: Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422970/how-does-join-work-in-java-does-it-guarantee-the-execution-before-main). If you have a thread `t` and you call `t.join()`, the current thread will wait until `t` has completed its execution or finished its task.

Comment: Ok, I have added the rest of the code, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yeah, so your thread doesn't actually do anything. You might want to read up on the [Oracle thread tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Comment: Both threads will execute, i am just trying to get them to run at the same time.

Comment: @Some_Dude methods are executed one after another because you call them one after another. You do not use threads in a proper way here. To make thread object do some stuff an a separate thread you need to put that stuff into `run()` method (without any input parameters). After that when you call `start()` code that `run()` method will be executed

Comment: @Some_Dude Both threads won't run at the same time. Only one runs at a time and this order is decided by the `Thread Scheduler`. And execution of another thread may start before the first one has completed its task. It's like `part of this and then part of that and so on...` You don't have control over how it runs and which completes first and so on by default. I mean placing `c.start()` after `t.start()` doesn't mean `c starts after t has finished its task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `Create()` and `Consume` methods inside `run()` method of your thread. Because now calling `T.Create()` and `c.consume()` in a usual serial manner.

Comment: You also need to override the run method that takes no arguments.

Comment: Yes, both called sequentially in the context of the main thread. I suggest starting playing with threads by reading the Oracle manuals to understand how it works, then playing with small, easy to follow examples first.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is a good idea to post code that can be ran on anyone else's computer (as minimal amount of code required) so that we can have a better time debugging your issue.

These link might help:

- http://coderscampus.com/java-multithreading-java-util-concurrent/
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: It is also a good idea to follow Java naming conventions and code style.  This really helps others to read your code, and avoids mistakes such as mixing classes and instances.